# I want to search for values greater than a specific number (e.g. 0) and list down adjacent cell values in MS Excel

Tags: arrays, excel

I have two columns of data with 'vehicle count' in first column and 'travel time' in second column. I want to search for rows with vehicle count greater than a specific number (e.g. 0) and list down adjacent cell values from the 'travel time' column.
[Data Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re2bE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `FILTER()` function like-

```
=FILTER(B:B,A:A>0)
```

> ***Edit:*** For Excel-2019 use below formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$100)/($A$1:$A$100>0),ROW($A1))),"")
```

> Edit2: As per attached screenshot use below formula-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$27,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(B$4:$B$27)-ROW($B$3))/($B$4:$B$27>0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Comment: I'm using MS Excel 2019 version which to my knowledge does not have filter function.

Comment: Hi Harun, your formula is working when the first row of the sheet starts with the data without any heading rows. It starts skipping values when I add heading rows above the dataset. After adding heading rows, I made sure that the selection area only consist of data rows in the formula.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad Then you need few changes to formula parameters. Can you show few sample data with header row so that I can correct then answer.

Comment: Hi Harun, please see my editted post with data sample.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad As per your screenshot try this formula `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$4:$C$27,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(B$4:$B$27)-ROW($B$3))/($B$4:$B$27>0),ROW(1:1))),"")`.

Comment: @SalmanAhmad I have posted this to my answer. Please accept it means tick mark the answer so that other can know your this problem is solved.